# React native upload multiple files (IOS + Android)

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, mobile, upload, file-storage

I have a case that we need to handle uploading up to 100 photos (like google photos).
We want to store them on our side (AWS s3 / Azure).
How to handle that on mobile / backend side?
Is there any library that will take care of core vulnerabilities like:

- background (if user will minimize the app during upload)
- error handler during the connection

Maybe someone has any idea how to handle that.

Im searching for SAAS / library to RN that will allow us to upload files for example to AWS s3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the same thing. The only library I could find that would handle background uploading like you are taking about is `expo-file-system`. It works pretty good the biggest issue that I have is that it doesn't provide a way to get active tasks if the app's suspended by the OS. It does however on iOS at least retry until it gets a response from the server even if you no longer have scope of the background process. Errors seem to be handled fine as long as the app stays in the background and execution isn't stopped by the OS. This is using the native android and iOS operating systems to send out these calls so the retry logic should be referred to on that native documentation.

Here is the documentation for `expo-file-system`:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem#filesystemcreateuploadtaskurl-fileuri-options-callback

Here is the native iOS documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background

Comment: I also found the:
react-native-background-upload

Comment: Yeah it works as you would expect with progress callbacks and everything it really just comes down to those rare cases that the app is suspended. I am not sure how often that would actually happen but it a little concern because you wouldn't really know where any tasks are at then you restart the app. Because of that I am in the process of writing my own library for this.

Comment: That being said I do think the expo-file-system would work for what you are trying to do and more often then not have no negative issues. It's just UI re-wire that you would be missing if the app was suspended the tasks will restart themselves perfectly and finish the process without any other setup from you.